# Google Chrome Extension and Application Development

Tags: java, google-chrome

I would like to develop a chrome extension/application from my java application.  Is this possible?  If so, could you please point me to some tutorials/resources?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK (at least when I was doing those things) chrome extensions can be written only in javascript.

Everything is here:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html